# Java "did you forget to inherit a required module" and getting a Method [GWT]

Tags: java, gwt

I'm using GWT and every time in compile it, i get a error saying

Line 435: The method getDeclaredMethod(String, Class[]) is undefined for the type Class

And line 435 is

m =  body_B.getUserData().getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getNumber",  null);

I know that the issue may be because GWT cannot see the same things as running the application.  but i don't know how to fix it, any suggestions ?

Im new to GWT, so im not too sure on what to do and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT code is translated to JavaScript and direct usage of reflection is not supported.

Comment: So how could i change the code to get the same result? any suggestions

Comment: You can either use an interface for common functionality or check out the GWT exporter project.

Comment: if i use a interface for object "body_B.getUserData()", what do i put in where null was?, or wouldn't i need to invoke it in the first place , thanks for the reply.

Comment: Never Mind in interfaces is a much better idea then invoking, so thanks so much for the help. I don't normally use interfaces much but it can be really useful. :)